# Is there an easier way to group cells to SUM them given dates associated with the summands?

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the sum of bond returns over a given month (each business day there is a new return that I need to sum). For example, in January of 1998, I have the following:

[image]

My goal is to sum up the right-hand column to find the cumulative return for each month. Because I have to find this for ~21 years worth of data, I don't think that doing the sum ranges by hand is a good idea. As such, I'm trying to figure out a way to use the dates already associated with the returns in order to sum over the month in question. Any suggestions would be welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Look into [`SUMIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) and [`SUMIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B)

Comment: Use a Pivot Table.  Group by Months and Years

Comment: Are you sure you want to **sum** daily returns to get a cumulative return? I don't think that's how the math works.

Comment: Agree on pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use an array formula (entered with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>), and adjust the ranges as necessary:

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH($B$1:$B$4)=D2,$A$1:$A$4,0))
```

Where `D3` is `1`, and you'd drag down and `D4` would be `2`, etc.:

[image]

Edit: To consider the year too, use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($B$1:$B$4)=E2)*(YEAR($B$1:$B$4)=D2)*$A$1:$A$4)
```

[image]

Comment: But this doesn't take in to account the **21 years** of data. This will sum all 21 January's to one sum not individually (as I think OP wants)

Comment: That's true, but I can do a similar thing for years as well I think.

Comment: @scoopfaze summing daily returns to get a cumulative return seems very suspect...